# bean-validation @Pattern the first digit is '1'

Tags: java, regex, hibernate, validation, bean-validation

How to use bean-validation @Pattern in the field below to check if the first digit is '1'?

```
  private Long registration;
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex bellow says it must start with 1 and have anything after that

```
 @Pattern (regexp = "^1.*$")
 private Long registration;
```

Comment: "must", not "can". Do you need `$`? One 'l' in 'below'.

Comment: Yes, is a "must". And I need $ because there will be another digits after '1'. Thanks for your comment, i will edit the answer to improve the explanation

Comment: Because `.*` is greedy it will gobble up all the characters to the end of the line. You don't need `$` to force it to do that.